# Can't be enable to @ignore annotation for the features

Tags: karate

Karate has @ignore annotation for the features.

https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

I try to @ignore annotation, but it is not enable and the feature runs.
(use karate 0.9.2)

How can I use @ignore annotation for the features?

```
@ignore
Feature: API test

Background:
* url 'http://localhost:8089'

Scenario: Get all rentacycles

    Given path '/rentacycles'
    When method get
    Then status 200
        And assert response.size() === 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "special" annotation (actually there is just one which is [`@parallel=false`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallelfalse))

So you can freely use any name for the annotation.

What is important is when you run your tests, you have to mention *which* annotation to use. See the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#tags

Maybe this example will be clear: [`first.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/tags/first.feature)

To run tests with a tag:

```
mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags @smoke"
```

And what you are asking is to NOT run:

```
mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags ~@smoke"
```

Normally this is set on the JUnit runner like [this example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/DemoTestParallel.java):

```
@KarateOptions(tags = "~@ignore")
```

Comment: >There is no "special" annotation (actually there is just one which is @parallel=false)

Is that true? I didn't know that.

I also try to use @KarateOptions, but it is not enable.

https://github.com/takanorig/example-karate/blob/master/src/test/java/examples/rentacycles/RentaCyclesRunner.java

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @takanorig I tried your code, I think it is working fine. if you comment out in the feature `#@ignore` it starts running. also just add this to `ExamplesTest` and your build will be green: `@KarateOptions(tags = "~@ignore") `

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It was able to enable @ignore annotaion.

Comment: @takanorig great !