# Feature with tag still being run when configured not to

Tags: testing, cucumber, integration-testing, karate

I have a main feature file where I have included a "setup" feature file that should add some test data.  This setup feature file has an annotation that I have called `@ignore`.  However, following the instructions in this [Can't be enable to @ignore annotation for the features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644498/cant-be-enable-to-ignore-annotation-for-the-features) SO answer, but I am still seeing the setup feature file being run outside of the main test feature.

Main feature file, `unsubscribe_user.feature`:

```
Feature: Unsubscribe User

  Background:
    * def props = read('properties/user-properties.json')
    * url urlBase
    * configure headers = props.headers
    * def authoriZation = call read('classpath:basic-auth.js')  { username: 'admin', password: 'admin' }
    * def testDataSetup = call read('classpath:com/meanwhileinhell/app/karate/feature/mockserver/testDataSetup.feature') { data1: #(props.data1), data2: #(props.data2) }

  Scenario: Unsubscribe user
   ...
   ...

  Scenario: Remove test data
   * def testDataTearDown = call read('classpath:com/meanwhileinhell/app/karate/feature/mockserver/testDataTearDown.feature') { data1: #(props.data1), data2: #(props.data2) }
   ...
```

`testDataSetup.feature` file

```
@ignore
Feature: Add data to REST Mock Server

  Background:
    * url mockServerUrlBase

  Scenario: Add data
    * print 'Adding test data'
    Given path 'mapping'
    And request { data1: '#(data1)', data2: '#(data2)' }
    When method post
    Then status 201
```

Now from my Java runner class, I have added `@KarateOptions(tags = "~@ignore")`.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.intuit.karate.KarateOptions;
import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Karate.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:com/meanwhileinhell/app/karate/feature/unsubscribe_user.feature")
@KarateOptions(tags = "~@ignore")
public class KarateTestUnSubscribeUserRunner {
}
```

However, I can still see my print statement in my setup class being called, and two POSTs being performed.  I have also tried running my suite with the following cmd options, but again, still see the feature file run twice.

`./gradlew clean test -Dkarate.env=local -Dkarate.options="--tags ~@ignore" --debug`

I am following this wrong somewhere?  Is there something I can add to my `karate-config.js` file?  I am using Karate version 0.9.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations only work on the "top level" feature. Not on "called" features.

If your problem is that the features are being run even when not expected, you must be missing something, or some Java class is running without knowing it. So please follow this process and we can fix it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

EDIT: I think I got it - please don't mix `CucumberOptions`, in fact we deprecated it, use only `KarateOptions`. Even that is not recommended in 0.9.5 onwards and you should move to JUnit 5.

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-options

Comment: Hi @PeterThomas, sorry for the lateness of replying to you.  I updated my tests to only use `KarateOptions` as you suggested.  And I think the main issue I was seeing was that I was calling the external `testDataSetup.feature` file inside the `Background` section using `call`.  After re-reading the docs I saw found `Cucumber has a limitation where Background steps are re-run for every Scenario`, and since my "tearDown" section was a separate Scenario, it was running the setup again.  Using the `callonce` hook fixed this a treat.